# Closed representation of Ladder operators in One Dimensional Second Order Homogeneous Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-theory

(1) Has anyone published the closed representation of ladder operators for second order differential equations?

More specifically the second order differential equation
$$
-\partial_x^2\Psi_m(x) + V(x)\Psi(x) = E_m\Psi_m(x)
$$
where $E$ is the eigenvalue. The ladder operator would satisfy $A_m\Psi_m=\Psi_{m+1}$.

(2) To relax the constraint on $A$, could one define it in terms of the potential and the energy spectrum, without know the eigenstates?

Comment: In this [MathOverflow answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/167503), Carl Beenakker discusses the explicit construction of ladder operators for the case of _factorizable_ Hamiltonians.

Comment: @Semiclassical I checked this paper. Am I interpreting this paper correctly, not all potentials $V(x)$ can be solved from that specified method?

Comment: Comparing with a book I have (Cooper et al, _SUSY in QM_), it seems that all Hamiltonians are factorizable, but explicitly expressing it as such requires the ground state to be known. That's easy enough for something like the harmonic oscillator, but such cases are the exception.

Comment: @Semiclassical Can these operators be constructed from the zero energy state?